# How to write the routes of ReactJs properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm writing my react routes in object basis. I could have written the routes in JSX components wise, but I felt more comfortable and this way the routes stays in one particular file, which is also easy to understand.

**Description:**
I'm trying to render the child route inside of the parent route. To avoid unnecessary loading of the entire page and navigating to / opening a new tab.

To render the child route inside of the parent route ReactJs provides a Component / Element called [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet).

**Problem:**
It seems I can't figure out the Architecture / Structure of how the routes will be.
Please help me figure this out.

**Attempts:**
I tried to do this approach. But react gives me an error saying `Error: Absolute route path "/user/all" nested under path "/user/profile/:userId" is not valid.`

How can I fix this?

```
{
    path: "/user/profile/:userId",
    element: <UserProfile />,
    children: [
       {
          path: "/user/all",
          element: <div>User all posts</div>,
       },
    ],
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a root path, `/user/all`, be a child of `/user/profile/:userid`. Typically child routes are extensions of the parent route, for example `/user/profile/:userid/all`

Comment: Then how should i write the route to display all the created posts of the user?

Comment: Is this not covered by [the tutorials](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#nested-routes)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, you are correct. In the tutorials they have showed similar to what I'm trying to achieve. But, in my case my child route depends on the parent route which have a `:userId`. In Simple terms if i have to say this is nested child route inside of another children route of the home route..

Comment: Kevin yes, i have updated my route after reading @tykhan answer. Which solved the error but child route element is not rendering. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't change your question after receiving an answer that solves it. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, i have reverted to previously asked original question

Answer (score 0):

When specifying ***nested*** routes the paths should be ***relative*** paths (*from the parent route*). You can't nest an absolute path that is different from the parent.

Example:

Parent path `"/user/profile"`

- Child path `"/user/profile/:userId"` - valid
- Child path `":userId"` - valid
- Child path `/user/profiles"` - ***invalid***

```
{
  path: "/user/profile/:userId",
  element: <UserProfile />,
  children: [
     {
        path: "all",
        element: <div>User all posts</div>,
     },
  ],
}
```

`UserProfile` is a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and ***necessarily*** needs to render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserProfile = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    ...
  );
};
```